# Rails 4.2 load balancing with nginx redis and sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

Hi I just launched a rails 4 application which uses nginx as load balancer with thin serving rails on 2 ports. Additionally I use redis as cache which is also getting used by sidekiq.

I was wondering how can I scale up using another machine in order to run two more rails applications there. My idea is just running two more rails applications on another machine but the headache comes with redis since sidekiq is making heavy use of it. My first idea was just to have another redis slave which is just read only on the second machine . But this might be error prone since I have a lot of writes into redis in order to check a worker queue.

The following scenario kind of confuses me. The web app makes a request and triggers sidekiq which performs a long running action, it continuously updates the status in redis. The web client polls the app every second in order to get the status. Now it could be possible that the request gets redirected to the second machine with the redis slave which is not yet updated. So  I was wondering how would be the best setup, just using one redis instance taking into account latency or run a redis slave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two machines:

1. MachineA running thin and sidekiq.
2. MachineB running thin and sidekiq.

Now you install redis on MachineA and point Sidekiq to MachineA for Redis.  Both Sidekiqs will talk to Redis on MachineA.  See [Using Redis](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis) for more detail.

Side note: A redis slave is useful for read-only debugging but isn't useful for scaling Sidekiq.

Comment: Oh Mike I did not expect to get an answer directly from you. That's great since you know best ;) Actually your solution was also the one I was having in mind. The only thing that makes me feel uncomfortable is the latency since I am running on a vm.